# (IN C) Why does this merging of two lists, other than doing the merging, also adds a lot of useless nodes?

Tags: c, list, memory, linked-list

Code for the structures:

```
typedef struct nodo_int *lista_int;

struct nodo_int{
    int info;
    lista_int next;
}nodo_int;
```

Code for visualizing the lists and merge alternating them in one:

```
void visNode(int value){
    printf("| %d |", value);
}

void visList(lista_int l){
    if(l != NULL){
        visNode(l->info);
        visList(l->next);
    }
}

lista_int alternateLists(lista_int l1, lista_int l2){
    lista_int l3 = makesNode();
    lista_int temp = l3, newNode = NULL;

    if(l1 == NULL)
        return l2;
    else if(l2 == NULL)
        return l1;

    while(l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL){
        newNode = makesNode();
        newNode->info = l1->info;
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = newNode;
        l1 = l1->next;

        newNode = makesNode();
        newNode->info = l2->info;
        temp->next = newNode;
        temp = newNode;
        l2 = l2->next;
        printf("\n1\n");

    }

    return l3->next;
}
```

In main:

```
int main(){
    lista_int l1, l2;
    l1 = generateList();
    l2 = generateList();    
    printf("\nFirst list:\n");
    visList(l1);
    printf("\n\nSecond lists:\n");
    visList(l2);
    printf("\n\nNew list obtained from merging the other two:\n");
    lista_int l3 = alternateLists(l1, l2);
    visList(l3);
    return 0;
}
```

The code does what it should, but also adds a lot of useless memory to the third list. I also tried debugging but it results in a false positive.

Comment: What results in a false positive? Is your structure definition missing a `typedef`?

Comment: I mean that the debug doesn't give me any answer, but the list is still full of useless nodes for some reason

Comment: Tip: type-deffing a pointer  like `typedef struct nodo_int *lista_int;` helps obfuscate code - harder to debug.  Consider `typedef struct nodo_int lista_int;` (no *) next time.

Comment: From a quick look I don't see "a lot" of extra nodes being created, but you are leaking memory in `alternateLists()`, since you allocate a dummy node at the start of `l3` that you don't free, and that is outside the part of the list you return.  Also, if the `l1` and `l2` lists are different lengths, you don't copy the nodes from the end of the longer list -- is that intentional?